# ¿Cómo asigno números a letras en Java?

Tags: java, variables, ordenamiento

¡Hola! Este es mi conflicto actual. Estoy intentando ordenar una lista con Counting Sort determinada por el propio usuario donde todos los elementos sean letras. Notoriamente, Counting Sort ordena primordialmente números y nada más que eso. Por lo que, mi idea principal es convertir o más bien, asignar a cada una de las letras un número en específico.
Por ejemplo, si quisiese ordenar: {a, b, c, c, b, a, a} mi idea es asignarle los siguientes números:

a = 1

b = 2

c = 3

d = 4

Para que de ese modo, se ordenen empleando el valor de los números. En este caso de ser: {1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1}, pasaría a ser: {a, a, a, b, b, c, c}. Y bueno, ese es mi razonamiento.
¿Tienen alguna sugerencia del cómo podría asignar dichos números a las letras? ¿Debería crear nuevas variables declarando cada letra como un número? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Simon, échale un vistazo a esta pregunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605891/sort-a-single-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Ejemplo:

asocias numeros con letras

```
HashMap<Integer,String>map=new HashMap<>();

    map.put(1,"a");
    map.put(2,"b");
    map.put(3,"c");
    map.put(4,"d");
```

luegode aplica tu counting sort

```
           //1,2,3,3,2,1,1


int [] ordenados={1,1,1,2,2,3,3};
```

imprime los valores o guardalos en un nuevo array

```
for (int i=0;i<ordenados.length;i++ ) {
        System.out.print(map.get(ordenados[i])+" ");
    }
```

salida

```
 a, a, a, b, b, c, c
```